# Docker volume mount path

Tags: docker, sqlite, docker-volume

I'm trying to get started with Docker volumes. I have a simple Python Flask app that stores data in an sqlite3 data base. Running the app in a container without a volume works, but of course, every time I restart the container, all DB data is lost.

I've tried to read the available documentation on how to use volumes and I created a new, named volume:

```sh
docker volume create mydb
```

But I don't get what path I have to specify when starting the container with the volume. If I just do

```sh
docker run -p 5000:5000 -v mydb:/db my-app
```

it still loses all data when restarting. What do path do I need to specify instead of `/db`? What does this depend on?

Comment: do you actually save the sqlite file under /db ?

Comment: No at `os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'mydb.sqlite')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`bind mounts`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)  or [`docker volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Assuming you selected `/<path-to-db>` as the location of the database inside the container, and `./data` is the folder on your host filesystem you'd like to use to persist the database, or `mydb` is the volume you use:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -v ./data:/<path-to-db> my-app
docker run -p 5000:5000 -v mydb:/<path-to-db> my-app
```

To find out which path inside the container you use to store the files (if you are not sure), look for [`sqlite3.connect`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlite3/) code: the argument is the path you need.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! And, in your example, `/data` could be an empty directory on my host to which all data from the container is copied?

Why would I not use the named volume `mydb` that I created earlier? The [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) say volumes are usually preferred over bind mounts.

Comment: You can use both, the point is that you need to use the correct path to the database inside your container, which is apparently not `/db`

Comment: @YuryFedorov what would be the equivalent of this path as defined inside a `docker-compose` file?

Answer (score 1):

Named Volumes should not lose the data, as explained in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/):

Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.

What you actually need is to ensure that you are saving the database to the correct directory that the named volume will use. I suggest creating a specific directory inside your flask app in order to save the sqlite3 file, then mount that directory to your named volume.
So for example your sqlite3 file path is: `/home/myflaskapp/db` then the mount will be as following otherwise you will lose the data because you have not mounted the correct path that you want to keep:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -v mydb:/home/myflaskapp/db my-app
```

Comment: Hm. I'd like to keep developing on Windows and Linux. What kind of absolute path could I specify that works under both systems?

The problem with my current relative path is that it behaves differently when using `python setup.py develop` vs `python setup.py install`.

Comment: by path i meant the path inside the container regardless of the host operating system, if you need to keep the database you need to add it to a specific directory